# Facebook Connect doesn't redirect upon login

Tags: facebook

I know this is a question that has been asked several times, but I'm receiving an error that I haven't found any documentation on and am not making any progress on this.

I have the Facebook Connect feature working on my blog, however, not everything is working.  Upon clicking the 'Login' button a popup is displayed that allows me to enter user/pass information.  After clicking 'Login' the page doesn't refresh and I receive a javascript error.

```
Error: this._opts.channelUrl is null
Source File: http://www.facebook.com/widgets/comments.php?api_key=XXXX&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.gnucom.cc%2Fxd_receiver.htm&xid=http%253A%252F%252Fblog.gnucom.cc%252F2010%252Ffacebooks-connect-on-wordpress%252F&width=550&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.gnucom.cc%2F2010%2Ffacebooks-connect-on-wordpress%2F&title=Facebook%E2%80%99s%20Connect%20on%20Wordpress.&numposts=10&css=&simple=&reverse=&quiet=&publish_feed=1&locale=en_US
Line: 2
```

If I refresh the page manually, I see that I actually was logged in.

Can anyone suggest a solution or point me to another post?  If this is actually a duplicate post please point me to the other post, and I'll close this one.

Thanks,

Edit:  I'm adding resources that I've found so far, but am not sure if they will resolve the issue.

1. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=37333
2. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=69660

Answer (score 0):

> This error is occuring because
>   "a.frameName" is set to
>   "iframe_canvas", but "a.channelUrl" is
>   set to NULL.  So when you call
>   "indexOf" on a NULL property, you get
>   that JavaScript error.

Comment: You can create channel.html and put this line of code in it...

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

Also you need to point to this file in FB config. Hope it solves problem...